# Link URL is empty for outbound clicks in exploration, what is wrong? (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, click, analytics, outbound

I'm trying to create an exploration view in Google Analytics that will show how many outbound clicks there were on my website, and which specific links were clicked.

I started with a blank project. My dimensions (and rows) are Outbound, Link domain, Link URL. Value is Event count. I'm just trying to get it to show the domain and URL of the outbound click.

[image]

Right now Link URL and Link Domain show nothing. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

I've tried multiple different online tutorials, following step by step (including Google's tutorial at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13566436?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), but so far nothing has worked as expected. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Very new to this.

Comment: Couple questions...How long has analytics been installed on the site? What is the date range your are looking at? Are you looking at data from the last couple days? Also, I believe the outbound clicks are tied to the enhanced measurement >> click event. Are you filtering by event name `click`?